# C# 2 dimensional array output to textbox

Tags: c#, arrays

Trying to get a simple 2 dimensional array to display to a text box. Output should look like this:

Student  Class  House
Jack     Math   Oxford
Bender   Chem   Trent

All previous attempts have failed and I am not sure how to output the code.

```
String[,] text = {
            { "Student", "Class", "House" },
            { "Jack", "Math", "Oxford" },
            { "Bender", "Chem", "Trent" } };

        //string textString;
        for (int i = 0; i < text.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
        {
            string first = text[i, 0];
            string middle = text[i, 1];
            string last = text[i, 2];

            TextBox1.Text = first;
            TextBox1.Text = middle;
            TextBox1.Text = last;


        }
```

Comment: You need to append string to the textbox. You need to use `+=` when assigning string to the textbox.

Comment: Have you considered using a DataGridView instead? Something with rows and columns...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to concatenate the text onto your strings and pass the strings to the texbox only once, after you're all done. You'll want to add in line breaks to have the data go over several lines as well.

Something like this (untested):

```
String[,] text = {
        { "Student", "Class", "House" },
        { "Jack", "Math", "Oxford" },
        { "Bender", "Chem", "Trent" } };

    string output = '';

    //string textString;
    for (int i = 0; i < text.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
    {
        output += text[i, 0] + text[i, 1] + text[i, 2] + Environment.NewLine;
    }

    TextBox1.Text = output;
```

At the moment you're just adding things to the textbox and then overwriting them on the next loop.

Answer (score 0):

so i think you problem that you are using textbox try textarea.
the reason is that textbox only take only line but textare you can have multiple lines and you are overwriting the  text of the textbox every time by doing this   TextBox1.Text = first;
                TextBox1.Text = middle;
                TextBox1.Text = last;
so try this better 
TextBox1.Text += first + " " + middle+" " + last;

Answer (score 0):

If both dimensions are dynamic, you can use a second loop nested it in the one you have. Each loop will be going through one dimension:

```
for (int i = 0; i < text.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < text.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        TextBox1Text += text[i, j] + "\t";
    }

    TextBox1.Text += "\r\n";
}
```

Note: I used tab `\t` to separate the columns and new line `\r\n` to separate the rows. However, this format will not be visible in a `textbox`, you'll need to use a `textarea`. Here is a [demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oCF4fC).